# Option from function called unintentionally, ignoring argument value, invalid argument and how to find largest file in directory and get its' size

Tags: bash, shell

An option from my script is being called into an echo where I don't want it to be called.
When I run the script with the option -r, it's called in the echo of "directory that doesn't exist."
So for example I run bash sdel.sh -r [dir] and even if that directory exists and is moved to trash directory, I still get the error message saying -r doesn't exist. If it doesn't exist I get 2 messages, 1 that says that directory doesn't exist and 1 that says -r doesn't exist.

Parameter processing:
( -r fixed)

```
while getopts "hr:t:s:u:" options; do
case $options in
...
# shift $((OPTIND-1))

r) tgtdir="${OPTARG}"

  if [ ! -d "${tgtdir}" ]; then
    echo "$0: error: tried to delete directory that does not exist: ${tgtdir}"
#   shift
    continue
  fi
  tarname="${tgtdir}.tar"
  tar -cf "$tarname" "${tgtdir}"
  mv "$tarname" $trash
  rm -r "${tgtdir}"
# shift

exit;; 

esac
done
```

In another option, t, I'm trying to delete files over x hours from user input but it always deletes whatever the value I put in. (FIXED)

```
t)
tgtdir="${OPTARG}"
now = `date +%s`
cd $trash
for f in `ls`; do
fileage=$(stat -c '%Y' "$f")

if [ $((now-fileage)) -gt $((60*60*${tgtdir})) ]; then
rm -rf "$f"
echo "Cleaning directory $trash"

else
echo "Nothing to clean in directory $trash"
fi
done
exit;;
```

Another one of them, s, is to find and delete files over x size in KB in the $trash directory but I'm getting an invalid argument when I try to run it.

(FIXED)

```
s)
tgtdir="${OPTARG}"
cd $trash
find . -type f -size +${tgtdir}k -delete
exit;;
```

In u, trying to get largest file in directory and its' size but currently, it still also gives me the directory back and I wanted it to be just the file. (FIXED)

```
u) find $trash -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | head-1
exit;;
```

Help's appreciated in solving each of these issues!

Comment: I would suggest you focus on one issue and then provide a minimal, fully functional set of code that reproduces the problem; also include a sample call to the code, the (correct) expected output and the (wrong) current output

Comment: Done, hopefully it's clearer what the issue is.

Comment: that is not a fully functional script; of key importance is how you're processing your input parameters (eg, `getopts` vs `for op in $@` vs ???); the fact the error message mentions `-r` seems to imply (to me) that there's an issue with how you're processing your input parameters ... but the code snippet you've provided doe not show us all of the code being used to process the input parameters

Comment: It's getopts, added that aswell now.

Comment: `-e file` ==> true if **file** exists; `-d` ==> true if file exists and **is a directory**

Comment: so swap -e with -d? Done, however the issue persists

Comment: the `r) while ... exit;;` goes inside the `case ... esac` block (code snippet updated); does `dir1` exist in the directory where you execute the script from? or does the script perform a `cd` into the parent directory where `dir1` would exist? commented out the top-level `shift` ... should probably comment out the others, too ... not sure why you're doing `shift` in conjunction with `getopts` (for this particular set of example calls)

Comment: It exists in the directory where the script is executed. I used the shift to try and fix this issue since it's supposed to skip a parameter, I wanted it to skip -r when it's called in the echo but didn't work

Comment: updated the `-r` processing ... if `-r` then load the argument (`dir11` in this case) into variable `${tgtdir}`, then perform tests/ops on `${tgtdir}`

Comment: Switched to that and the error on -r is fixed, thanks a lot!

Comment: Did the same on option t and that one is also fixed.

Comment: Again, did the same to option s) and no longer get invalid argument error, however it still doesn't delete files larger then input

Comment: `set -xv; find ... ; set +xv`; this will echo the actual `find` command to stdout; you can then play with said command at the command line to see if it does what you want it to, and if not then play with the command until it does work and then update the code to mimic what you get working at the command line

Comment: I didn't quite understand, so I have to use both set and find?

Comment: add `set -xv` on line before the `find`, add `set +xv` on line after the `find`; these `set` commands turn on/off detailed debugging to show you the actual `find` command

Comment: I was wrong, it actually works, I'm an idiot and had directories inside while trying to delete the compressed files created by the script. So, in fact option -s is also fixed. The only thing I have no clue on how to do is how to find the largest file and that file alone and get its' size

Comment: Alright so I sort of found a way to do it using `sudo du -a $trash | sort -n -r | head -n 2` but this also gives me the actual directory and I just want the largest file and its size. Any way of doing this without the directory?

Comment: nvm sudo looks for directories aswell updated the post with fixes for every single one, thanks for the help in figuring it out